# Avoid app to autoinstall

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a "ZOPO ZP100" phone with Android 4.0.3. Eventually applications (Chinese) are installed without my permission. Any human action is not necessary for applications to be installed, and is quite annoying as it often happens that the phone stops working until the app is installed. I would like to know how to avoid that, or at least know if there is any way to know which application or process that performs that action.

Comment: Is your phone rooted? If so there are things you can do and I can help you but if not then unless you can get it rooted to get superuser access, you are at the mercy of the image and how it has been configured by the provider.

Comment: Could an app you've installed yourself be behind that? I'd recommend checking for apps having the `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission, as only those could do things like this. And to do it without user interaction, usually suggests an app with root permissions, as that permission has the protection-level "signatureOrSystem".

Comment: I think it is an application that comes with the phone. The phone is Chinese and all applications are autoinstalled, they do in Chinese

@gardian: Yes, my phone is rooted